# psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "C"

Tags: python, psycopg2

```
hwid1 = str(subprocess.check_output(
    'wmic csproduct get uuid')).split('\\r\\n')[1].strip('\\r').strip() # Get Hard Ware Id of the pc



def AutoUpdateDB():
    SQL.execute(f"select hwid from Accounts WHERE hwid = {hwid1}")
    result_user = SQL.fetchone()
    print(result_user[0])
    time.sleep(5555)
```

i am trying this code and its giving me error 
i tried to solve this but its still not working

here is the error

psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "C" 
LINE 1: ...ect * from Accounts WHERE hwid = AD902276-A4F9-961C-492B-2CF...

```
                                                         <br/>^
```

Comment: You probably need to escape `hwid` with quotes `"SELECT hwid FROM Accounts WHERE hwid='{hwid1}'"`

Comment: i dont think but let me try

Comment: Its worked Thank you! @C.Nivs

Answer (score 1):

Others have already pointed out why you are getting the specific error you are getting, but I would like to mention that the way around it is nearly always to use [parametrized queries](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries), i.e. something like

```
SQL.execute("SELECT hwid FROM Accounts WHERE hwid = %s", [hwid1])
```

This can save you no end of headaches if hwid1 contains "funny" characters.